# Redis conditional retrieve and delete records

Tags: redis

We are using mysql as message queue, now we want to change from mysql to redis.

We are facing few difficulties to implement the same logic of mysql in redis.
In Mysql the process as follows:

- Bulk insert into mysql database using load data infile.
- in other php script we select the records order by priority with conditions and delete those records from database and process those records

How we can achieve same in redis?

- in redis we are able to insert bulk data using pipe with lpush like key and json_encoded data

how can we get the data from redis key order by priority with some conditions and delete those records from redis?

We have table structure in mysql as below:

`` CREATE TABLE `message_queue` (
 `sql_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `msgdata` text,
 `pid` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `receiver` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `time` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
 `udhdata` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`sql_id`),
 KEY `pid` (`pid`),
 KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ``

SELECT and delete queries

`SELECT * FROM message_queue  WHERE (time = 0 OR time <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) ORDER BY pid DESC, sql_id ASC limit 500;`


`DELETE FROM message_queue WHERE sql_id in(ids_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy most of the requirements you'll need to decompose your data into several data structures.

Insert:

1. Every record from your `message_queue` table should be stored in a Hash - `sql_id` looks like a good key name candidate.
2. Keep a Sorted Set, e.g. `message_by_time` where each member is the `sql_id` and the score is `time`.

Query:

1. Use `ZRANGEBYSCORE message_by_time 0 0` and `ZRANGEBYSCORE message_by_time -inf <replace-with-timestamp>` to get the initial range.

Delete:

1. Call `DEL` and `ZREM` for each element.

Your requirements also specify the need to sort and limit - these can also be done in Redis, but I recommend handling them in the code instead.